# Is this possible to generate PDF from doxygen latex same as html output theme without any manual editing in refman.tex?

Tags: doxygen

I tried to make pdf from latex by following manual of doxygen. Its output is totally colorless and design is very lame.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if you're not including the required style sheets.